# Any way to attach specific CSS styles to specific groups?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have li already styled in a stylesheet. I need it to stay a specific style. It is styled without using a class, so for example
    .selectors{width:50px;}
    li{
        padding:10px;
    }

Now i have run into a problem. I am trying to style the li again, without any classes like what i have in the example code. For example
    .options {width:30px;}
    li{
    padding:50px;
    }

What i was wondering is, is there any way to attach certain elemnts to another element. I'm not sure if this is making any sense, but I am trying to have one LI only be applied to a certain part of the page, and the second be applied to another part of the page. Is this possible without using classes? I can't modify the code or add classes otherwise the script doesn't work. Can someone help if I am making any sense at all.

Comment: Take a look at Selectors:
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/

there are many more combinations you could use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very common way to do this is

```
#content li { ... }
#sidebar li { ... }
```

so the `li` will behave differently inside two different elements with different IDs.  Say, if `content` is a div, and `sidebar` is a div, then the `li` will behave differently inside these two divs.

It is also possible to be "within a class":

```
.items-to-watch-out-for li { ... }
```

This is a good way to avoid "too many classes", which is called "classitis", like in this article:

http://www.ehow.com/how_2284990_classitis-html-css-descendant-selectors.html

Comment: By the way, the `#` sign grabs the element by its ID.

Answer (score 0):

It's never going to be the nicest way if you can't add classes.

Potentially if the `ul`s are in the same container you could try:

```
ul:first-child li {}
```

This will allow you to style the first `ul` however you want then the generic:

```
ul li {}
```

Will take care of the second.

This method should work in all browsers apart from IE6.

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t17

動靜能量 solution is the ideal way.